# Does 青山 (aoyama) mean green or blue or black mountain?

Tags: meaning

It must be weird for being blue or black ... but is it really green?

All usages of 青 I've read so far mean blue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the most part, 青 has come to express the colour blue and 緑 expresses green, but there are some words or phrases which use the older meaning of 青 that encompassed both shades.

*[EDIT]* As pointed out by Leebo in the comments, there is also the word 青毛 (black horse coat colour) wherein the black sheen may have a blue tinge, but words with such usages are interesting exceptions rather than the norm.

The distinction between blue and green in the Japanese language is relatively recent, apparently ([Wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blue%E2%80%93green_distinction_in_language#Japanese)). So while there is a word for green (みどり) now, both colours used to be expressed only with the word 青. That has led to an unusual situation whereby occasionally context and convention determine which colour is intended by using 青. For example, 青りんご is obviously 'green apple' and not 'blue apple'. Likewise, 青森 could be literally translated as 'green forest' since trees are green and not blue. The traffic light 青信号 is called a green light in English but in Japan the shade of green used in the actual light does seem to have a blue tinge, so that one is debatable. But the point remains that basically, 青 = blue and 緑 = green, with some exceptions that have remained from older times.

Therefore, 青山 would be 'green mountain', presumably referring to the mountain being covered in green trees.

Comment: The only word I'm aware of where black seems to be indicated is 青毛, which describes the, primarily, black coat of a horse.

Comment: Thank you! You made it all clear.

Comment: @Leebo Ｉ’ｄ never heard that word before. It would be interesting to find out the origin of that. Maybe it's the blue-black sheen on the coat? May I edit my answer to include your addition?

Comment: @kandyman Yeah, that's fine, here's a definition https://www.weblio.jp/content/%E9%9D%92%E6%AF%9B It does come from the sheen of the coat rather than the black coat itself.

Comment: Interesting stuff!

Comment: Another curious expression related to the color green is 緑の黒髪.

Comment: I'm not sure you can argue it means "green mountain". Worldwide, several mountains are called "blue mountain" (see eg. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blue_Mountain) but I think only a range in Vermont is called "green mountains". Trees give off aerosols that give the air a blue tinge, but it's only noticeable for certain mountains with the right geography. Almost all mountains are green from vegetation so "green mountain" is not a very descriptive place name, whereas a blue tinge is more specific and characteristic and better for naming. Do we know which specific mountain this 青山 refers to?

Comment: It's a common family name in Japan. Such names are often based on simple geographical descriptions, i.e. Mountain-River (Yamakawa), Small-Island (Kojima), Forest-Under (Morishita), Bamboo-Inside (Takeuchi), etc. Thick vegetation on mountains is very common in Japan, so it is likely that the name Aoyama is just a simple description of the green appearance of a mountain from a distance.

Comment: @kandyman Ah, ok, I didn't realise it's a family name, I thought it was a place name for an actual mountain. Ok, your explanation makes sense then.

Comment: It is also the name of a place in Tokyo, but it's not specifically attached a mountain.